# pageAction onClick no respond

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I added the click event listener in a working sample app (pageAction) but I have no idea where has gone wrong. Take a look at 2 of this file:

my manifest json

```
{
  "name" : "Page action by content",
  "version" : "1.1",
  "description" : "Shows a page action for HTML pages containing a video",
  "background" : {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action" :
  {
    "default_icon" : "video-19.png",
    "default_title" : "There's a <video> in this page!"
  },
  "permissions": [ "declarativeContent" ],
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "video-48.png",
    "128" : "video-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [
        // When a page contains a <video> tag...
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          css: ["video"]
        })
      ],
      // ... show the page action.
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
    }]);
  });

});


 chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

I even put the click function within chrome.runtime, nothing happen. I don't think I forgot to reload the extension pack.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm having the same problem using the same example.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you cannot access the content of the active tab, hence your `chrome.tabs.executeScript` failed.

Try to acquire ["activeTab" permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) in addition.